# C bash на python часть 2

Tags: python, bash

Всем привет.
Есть скрипт на bash

```
#/bin/bash
. "/etc/CFG_FULL.cfg"

#nmap --excludefile $pwd/db_ip_exclude.txt -sn 192.168.212.0/22 | egrep -v "Host|nmap" | awk '{print $5}' > $pwd/db_ip_test.txt

cd $pwd/port_up_down
#ip=192.168.213.50
while read ip
do
cat /dev/null > $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
#/home/user/test/port_up_down/port_status.sh $ip
cat /var/log/remote/switches.log | grep -w $ip | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' |     sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
cat /var/log/remote/switches.log.1 | grep -w $ip | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
zcat /var/log/remote/switches.log.2.gz | grep " $ip " | grep Port | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort -n | uniq >> $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log
cat $pwd/port_up_down/tmp/tmp_$ip.log | sort -n | uniq > $pwd/port_up_down/log/$ip.log
done < $pwd/db_ip_test.txt
```

переписываю его на python:
С подсказками из предыдущего поста получилось вот что:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from string import *
import MySQLdb
import operator
import array

seen = []

fIP = open("db_ip_test.txt")
xString = fIP.readlines()
fIP.close()
nambers = len(xString)
xString = [xString.replace("\n","") for xString in xString]
for cntr in range(0,nambers):
    fOut = open("log/" + xString[cntr] + ".log", "w")
    print (xString[cntr])
    select_sql = "SELECT `msg` FROM `logs` WHERE host = '{0}' and msg LIKE '{1}'     ORDER BY `logs`.`msg` ASC;"
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="121788",db="syslog")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select_sql.format(xString[cntr],'Port% link%'))
    for k in cursor.fetchall():
      k = str(k)
      k = k.split()
      k = k[1]
      for d in range(len(cursor)):
    if d == k:
      d = k
      fOut.write(k + '\n')
      print (k)
    fOut.close()
```

Пока что смог реализовать сортировку только с помощью мускуля, хотелось бы более прямой способ.
Вопрос вот в чем, как отсортировать данные в массиве и удалить дубли.

Мне нужен аналог команды **sort -n** и **uniq**
вот кусок файла db_ip_test.txt:

```
192.168.212.32
192.168.212.50
192.168.212.51
192.168.212.52
```

вот вывод лога /var/log/remote/switches.log:

```
1
Aug 20 18:08:13 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link down
Aug 20 17:08:15 192.168.33.215 342236: Aug 20 18:08:14.617 XMAO: %PIM-6-INVALID_RP_JOIN: Received (*, 224.1.1.160) Join from 192.168.46.2 for invalid RP 150.158.231.8
Aug 20 18:08:16 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex
Aug 20 18:08:27 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link down
Aug 20 18:08:32 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex
Aug 20 17:08:37 192.168.215.250 INFO: Port 32 link up, 100Mbps  FULL duplex
Aug 20 10:20:25 192.168.212.72 INFO: Port 17 link down
Aug 20 10:20:28 192.168.212.72 INFO: Port 17 link up, 10Mbps  FULL duplex
Aug 20 10:20:36 192.168.212.72 INFO: Port 17 link down
Aug 20 17:08:58 192.168.215.250 INFO: Port 32 link down
Aug 20 17:09:00 192.168.215.250 INFO: Port 32 link up, 100Mbps  FULL duplex
Aug 20 18:09:02 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link down
Aug 20 18:09:07 192.168.213.134 INFO: Port 2 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex
```

вот вывод моего python скрипта:

[LOG](http://pastebin.com/nsjvwGVZ)

Ответ был дан на [форуме](http://python.su/forum/topic/22124/?page=1) в 6 посте
Пользователем s0rg

Comment: Если у Вас есть выбор - делать сортировку и удаление дубликатов в базе и средствами питона, то я бы выбирал первое. Это будет и быстрее и красивее.

Comment: не очень. выносить нужно конечно же.

Comment: Мне бы для начала чтоб скрипт заработал, а оптимизировать буду его позже.

Comment: Удалять дубли в mysql я не могу, только сортировать.

Comment: так

    SELECT DISTINCT ...

Comment: Если у Вас `IP` имет вид `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, то в bash скрипте Вы сортируете в числовом порядке только по первой `xxx`. 

Кстати, у sort есть ключик `-u`, поэтому `uniq` лишняя команда.

Comment: Покажи кусок лога.

Comment: @avp см мой коммент к [предыдущему вопросу](http://hashcode.ru/questions/244894/mysql-c-bash-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)

Comment: Хороший скрипт. 

Интересно, зачем тогда ТС эта морока с питоном и sql?

Comment: @eicto  
    SELECT DISTINCT ...

Не подходит, так как в мускуле данные храняться в виде:  
    Port 3 link down  
    Port 3 link up, 100Mbps  FULL duplex

Comment: ну это разные строки, почему это их нужно считать дублями ?

Comment: Мне в скрипте нужны данные только по номеру порта, поэтому мне и нужно удалить дубли не в базе а в скрипте

Comment: @Izya12, знаете в чем Ваша **реальная** проблема?

*Вы задачу не описали*.

Из последнего комментария становится ясно -  Вам надо для каждого введенного IP напечатать порты (без повторов), а не перевести кривоватый для решения именно этой задачи шелл-скрипт на питон.

Посмотрите на [структуру данных set](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) в питоне, IMHO это поможет.

--

Кстати, структура данных в SQL-базе (и алгоритмы ее заполнения данными) нам тоже неизвестна. Стоит ли после этого рассчитывать получить быстрые и качественные советы???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -n | uniq
```

Можно заменить на

```
def uniq(arr):
    arr.sort()
    j = []
    for i in xrange(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i-1] != arr[i]:
            j.append(arr[i])
    return j
```

Эта функция сначала сортирует массив с ip-адресами, переданными в нее, затем в цикле проверяет на дубли и возвращает отсортированный массив без дублирования.